Seeking Reference for Identity Involving Binomial Coefficients
I'm seeking a reference for the following identity:
Given positive integers $a_i,b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ satisfying the conditions:
\begin{align}
a_1&\leq b_1\\
a_1+a_2&\leq b_1+b_2\\
&\vdots\\
a_1+\cdots +a_k&\leq b_1+\cdots+b_k\\
\end{align}
, then we have
$${\sum_{i=1}^k} {a_i\choose 2}\leq {\sum_{i=1}^k} {b_i\choose 2}$$

I'm also happy with a straightforward proof derived from a theorem.

You won't find any reference, the claim is not true.
$$
1\leq 2\\
1+3\leq 2+2\\
$$
but
$$
3=\binom{1}{2}+\binom{3}{2}\not\leq \binom{2}{2}+\binom{2}{2}=2.
$$
